# How to run a binary file from crontab?

Tags: cron

I’m trying to execute a binary file created by PyInstaller from a python code from crontab. I have tried to insert many lines by using “crontab -e” but the binary file was not executed.

Example of the crontab commands I have tried:

```
* */12 * * * Path/dist/BinaryFile > LogFile.txt
* */12 * * * open Path/dist/BinaryFile > LogFile.txt
* */12 * * * root Path/dist/BinaryFile > LogFile.txt
* */12 * * * root open Path/dist/BinaryFile > LogFile.txt
```

Do you have any idea on how to execute this binary file?
I’m trying to execute those command on Ubuntu 16.04 VPS server.

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 17):

Use an absolute path:

```
* */12 * * * /Path/dist/BinaryFile > LogFile.txt
```

In addition, the file has to be executable. This can be done with `chmod +x /Path/dist/BinaryFile`.

Note that the [time is probably not what you want](https://crontab.guru/#*_*/12_*_*_*), but it will run just fine.

Comment: Don't forget to redirect stderr too: `* */12 * * * /Path/dist/BinaryFile > LogFile.txt 2>&1`  Otherwise, you can fill up mail with errors.

Comment: Hello, I have tried this and also tried the following command (* */12 * * * root /bin/chmod +x /root/program/dist/BinaryFile > LogFile.txt 2>&1) but the program is still not running. the problem is not in the binary because it's working fine when i click on (i use a gui in my vps). thank you in advance

Comment: You're aware [when it will run](https://crontab.guru/#*_*/12_*_*_*)?

Comment: Yes of course. And for testing the program i'm using a command that must make the program execute every 5 minutes (Ex: # */5 * * * * chmod +x  /root/follow-back/dist/FollowBack > FollowBackLog.txt)

Comment: @ZikoCpp `/bin/chmod +x /root/program/dist/BinaryFile` doesn't run the file, it changes its permissions. You need to do that once if the file isn't already executable, but the line in your crontab should just include the `/root/follow-back/dist/FollowBack > FollowBackLog.txt`  part as stated in this answer. Also, you realize that the `#` at the beginning of the line you pasted there disables its execution, right?

Comment: hello, i already tried (/root/follow-back/dist/FollowBack > FollowBackLog.txt) but i'm using # in those commands. should i remove them (it's the first time i'm trying to use crontab).

Comment: @ZikoCpp Yes, `#` starts a comment, so `cron` ignores that line. Specifically, "Lines whose first non-space character is a pound-sign (#) are comments, and are ignored." [src](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/)

Comment: Ok, i will try this and will be back soon

Comment: It's working know. thank you very much Kevin and vidarlo for help.